# Bad Gateway 502 Nodejs Cloud Panel

Tags: node.js, web, cloud, hosting, cpanel

I want to host my node app online and I have a debian 11 VM with Cloud Panel but when I create a node js app

it says Bad Gateway 502 nginx the server domain is divyansh.isync.in now I am using cloud panel for the first time and I have root access to the server via ssh. Can someone assist me on what to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the PORT you defined when creating the Node Site from cloude Panel is the same as which your node app is running on. that can cause this issue as well so make sure you use the same PORT in Node App before starting the node server.

if your app is already running and you want to change the PORT

- first stop the node app
- then update the PORT on your user settings
- and start the App again

that should solve your issue